# PHP set default time zone is not accurate

Tags: php, date, timezone

I am on the east coast. When I Google what time it is in denver and compare it to the output from my timezone change:

```
$SiteSettings = new SiteSettings();
$settings = $SiteSettings->getSettings();

date_default_timezone_set($settings["data"]["timezone"]);

echo date_default_timezone_get(), '--', date("Y-m-d g:i:a"),'<br />';
```

The time is 1 hour off but the timezone from the database is America/Denver. Is this because PHP `date` functions are not accurate, 
or because Google and PHP date point to slightly different timezones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have hard coded `America/Denver` as default timezone and its working fine, example:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
echo date_default_timezone_get(), '--', date("Y-m-d g:i:a"),'<br />';
?>
```

[Codepad Output](http://codepad.org/7XlBAlXV)

[Google Result](https://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy-ab&q=America%2FDenver+time&oq=America%2FDenver+time&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i22i30l3.607.3932.1.4231.9.7.2.0.0.0.191.1039.0j7.7.0....0...1c.1.19.psy-ab.0vIcdbcgbyE&pbx=1&fp=1&biw=1366&bih=655&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&cad=b)

Comment: Hmm... I just hardcoded it and about an 1 hour off everywhere. I wonder if my server has something to do with it then, maybe its not UTC or what it needs to be.

Comment: I just checked my server and sure enough, time zone was right but the time is still 1 hour off. I think they need to run that ntpupdate.